# How can I run a desktop website (like Youtube) in background in a webview, like chrome does?

Tags: android, webview

I want to run Youtube desktop website in the background (even if the screen gets off). For that, I made an application which has webview and it loads desktop site of youtube. It works perfectly on foreground, but when I pressed the home button or lock screen button it stops working. So I need a logic that can run webview in the background like chrome does when we open the desktop version of  Youtube website.

I tried to run webview in another thread but it gives me exception (Webview can run in UI thread only)

Comment: I am not sure if this can be done , since the WebView is just a View inside a fragment or activity and is bound by the life-cycle of the same. It will eventually stop to respect the fragment/activity life-cycle. Also  you might not be able to update the webview created on UI thread from some other thread.

Comment: But Google Chrome can do it. You can see by inserting youtube.com URL and check desktop site option from menu placed at the up-right side corner. I want to know how can chrome do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the similar is what done here http://afra55.github.io/2017/04/26/floating_view/
Run foreground service and attach WebView directly to window from that service. It may be hidden to user but has been still attached to context. As I know you have to request ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION to do that

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion. Let me try this.